# How to redirect from one Controller Action to annother action .. I am using this approach RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Home Controller and inside the Login Action if i have success in login i want to move to Index Action of the Admin Controller .I am using following approach

```
  //return View("../Admin/Index"); 
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

Both of this approaches are not working for me I am still in the index action of the Home Controller

```
 public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (IsValid(userName, password))
        {
            //return View("../Admin/Index"); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
            return PartialView("_login");   
        }

    }
```

Comment: just debug and check whether it is coming inside if statement or not..i think the `IsValid()` method is returning false and the control is coming in else case always..

Comment: I have checked it is Coming to the If and entering into the if block with true condition

Comment: And you have verified that `AdminController` has the following method declaration?  `public ActionResult Index() { ... }`

Comment: what have you wrote in Action "index" of "admin" controller?put the debugger on the index of admin controller and check whether it is executing the code  or not.

Comment: @McCee if the action is not mentioned in controller then MVC through exception instead of redirecting to previous page.

Comment: yes in my AdminController i have follwing Action  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();           
        }   and i have set the  break point but its not hitting

Comment: Is there any path problem ... because i have hosted my application in IIS with virtual directory BApp and my application url is http://localhost:49996/BApp/

Comment: You are using areas in your application???

Comment: Have you define some attribute for the controller or action which prevent the execution of the controller or method?

Comment: I have not use area in my application

Comment: attributes for controller .... I am not getting you

Comment: [Authorize]...like that

Comment: just check whether you are using some action filter something like [Authenticate] ... something in square brackets.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (IsValid(userName, password))
            {
                //return View("../Admin/Index"); 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
               
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
                return PartialView("_login");   
            }
          
        }  this is my login post from where i want to redirect to

Comment: have you wrote like this in admin controller.   [Authorize] public class AdminController : Controller { public ActionResult Index() { return View();} }

Comment: or   public class AdminController : Controller { [Authorize] public ActionResult Index() { return View();} }

Comment: No... nothing like that

Comment: can u please copy paste the admin controller.

Comment: if you remove your application from iis and run in local environment then is it working fine ?

Comment: no i have done that but its not working

Comment: have u put debugger on admin -- > index ? is the debugger execute the action ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66093/discussion-between-debashrita-and-user3217843).